# MySQL get unique values in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help. Basically, I'm trying to get unique values from my tables. I have three tables namely: conversations, conversation_messages and users.

**Conversations Table:**

```
conversation_id   user_id   friend_id
1                 1         2
2                 6         1
3                 1         7
4                 1         3
```

**Conversations_Messages Table:**

```
cm_id  conversation_id   sender_id  recipient_id  message
1      1                 1          2             Hello!
2      1                 2          1             Hi!
3      1                 1          2             Hola!
4      2                 6          1             Ola!
5      2                 1          6             Gutentag!
6      3                 1          7             Eow
7      4                 1          3             Eophu
```

Users Table:

```
user_id     name 
1           Test
2           Pat
6           Ela
7           Sophia
```

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT c.conversation_id, cm.message, 
                    CONCAT(u.firstname, ' ', u.lastname) AS sender, 
                    CONCAT(u2.firstname, ' ', u2.lastname) AS recipient
FROM `conversations` AS c 
JOIN conversation_messages AS cm
ON c.conversation_id = cm.conversation_id
JOIN users AS u
ON cm.sender_id = u.user_id
JOIN users AS u2 
ON cm.recipient_id = u2.user_id
WHERE c.user_id = 1
GROUP BY cm.conversation_id
```

**RESULTS:**

```
conversation_id   message   sender  recipient   
1                 Hello!     Test    Pat
2                 Ola!       Ela     Test
3          
etc...
```

I'm getting results but the first messages are being returned. I need to return the latest (by cm_Id) message. Any ideas? I would gladly appreciate thy help!

Comment: Please edit your question.  "Unique values per table" is rather ambiguous.  You should also provide desired results to match the sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of simple "FROM ... JOIN ..." use something like that

```
FROM `conversations` AS c 
JOIN      (
              SELECT    MAX(cm_id) max_id, conversation_id 
              FROM      conversation_messages 
              GROUP BY  conversation_id
          ) cm_last ON (cm_last.conversation_id = c.conversation_id)
JOIN      conversation_messages cm ON (cm.cm_id = cm_last.max_id)
```

It will found last cm_id for each conversation and then joined full conversation_messages with that ids, not first one.

Comment: Thanks, just a correction, you have typed c.customer_id instead of c.conversation_id

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you can get this by adding "ORDER BY cm.cm_id  DESC" at the end.